# Inserting and retrieving data from MySQL database from AngularJS site

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs

As a learning project I have been using AngularJS to create a quiz website.  I having a web hosting package with 123-reg.co.uk and managed to create a MySQL database with a table I hope to store peoples scores who complete the quiz.

Ultimately this means I will be able to build a scoreboard on my site.  I am hoping to create two functions in my site, one which will retrieve the scores and one which will post new scores.  I believe in order to achieve this I will need to use PHP to retrieve and post data however I am a little unsure where to start.

If anyone could provide me with some pointers I would be grateful as I am not particularly familiar with MySQL databases or PHP.  I did find [this](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/how-do-i-connect-to-my-mysql-database-4178/) guide on connecting to MySQL database from 123reg.co.uk however I am struggling.

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial that you mentioned is outdated, relies on `mysql_connect` that was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and removed on PHP 7.0.0. Find a more up to date tutorial that uses `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Also you will need to learn some security concerns, I really recommend you to study a bit before doing this, since you can have serious problems if implement a insecure script to do this.

There are great PHP Frameworks that implement all of this in a secure and easy way, try searching for [Laravel Framework](http://laravel.com). Isn't for begginers, but with a little knowlegend of PHP Object-oriented and MySQL (or any SQL supported by Laravel) you can do what you want.

There are also a nice site to learn Laravel, called [Laracasts](http://www.laracasts.com) with very nice screen-casts teaching Laravel (for begginers or not).